# Inheritance in table creation for basic structure reuse, and only it

Tags: postgresql

It is rare to use [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html) ([DDL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html))... And the most popular alternative is the [CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html), because is simple and reliable for non-experts. See examples below.

**Is there are a way to define a "table template" with no data and no risk of "unpredictable behaviour"?**

- Need structure and constraints copied from "table template";
- Need "no surprise" from "table template";
- Need similar thing for `FUNCTION ... RETURNS ... table_template`.

### Examples and details

```sql
CREATE TABLE cities_tpl ( -- need it only as a "table template"
  name       text,
  population real,
  elevation  int
);
CREATE TABLE capitals (
  state      char(2)
) INHERITS (cities);
```

This is complex to use, but this alternative below is simple and **predictable** for non-experts:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cities_tpl (
  name       text,
  population real,
  elevation  int
);
CREATE TABLE capitals AS SELECT * FROM cities_tpl WITH NO DATA;
ALTER TABLE capitals ADD COLUMN state char(2);
```

As [commented here](https://dzone.com/articles/table-inheritance-whats-it-good-for), we can define a secure "table template" for "no inheritance of data". The suggestion is to use

```sql
CREATE TABLE cities_tpl (
  name       text,
  population real,
  elevation  int,
  check (false) NO INHERIT  -- this line REALLY (?) do the magic??
);
CREATE TABLE capitals (
  state      char(2),
  UNIQUE (state,name)
) INHERITS (cities);
```

This is more elegant and easy to define, but it is not easy to check the "other magic", there are something to be remembered that differ from "CREATE TABLE AS"?

---

PS: [TYPE and DOMAIN](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/create_user_defined_type) are only for complex datatypes, not for TABLEs.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you maybe looking for `create table new_table like template_table`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, I and my colleagues  never use `INHERITS` for fear, but I think we can use "with no fear" as "table template"... The question is in bolds, but perhaps need a better English or more details... What you suggest?

Comment: Well, the answer would be `create table ... like ...`

Comment: Oops, look (!), there are a `LIKE` clause, it is new for me, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html  Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name!  So, delete this question?

Comment: No, @a_horse_with_no_name could convert that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there are a way to define a "table template" with no data and no risk of "unpredictable behaviour"?

Create a regular table:

```
CREATE TABLE cities_tpl 
( 
  name       text,
  population real,
  elevation  int
);
```

Then use `create table .. like ..`

```
create table capitals (like cities_tpl);
alter table capitals add state text;
```

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.6) you can copy constraints using the `including`, e.g. `including all` or `including constraints including indexes`

```
create table capitals (like cities_tpl including all);
alter table capitals add state text;
```

---

There is a difference to using inheritance however: when using inheritance, columns added to the "base" table are automatically available to all child-tables. This is not the case when you use `create table ... (like ...)`

Comment: Hum.. Testing LIKE with a table with constraints... No way to **copy constraints** with LIKE clause? I also edited the question to add your request of *"exactly is your question?"*, listing typical needs there... So, we can cite here `FUNCTION etc() RETURNS cities_tpl` as a way to reuse  table template.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: regarding  constraints, see my edit. No you can't use this as the base return type for a set returning function. For that you will have to use inheritance

Comment: Hi, we can use LIKE with functions! I am using pg v12... Ok, classic `CREATE FUNCTION test() RETURNS foo  AS 'select * from foo limit 2' language SQL immutable;` returns only one row, **is bad**;  but, now using TABLE and LIKE, it is working fine!  `CREATE FUNCTION test() RETURNS TABLE (LIKE foo) AS 'select * from foo limit 2' language SQL immutable;`. It works with `SELECT * FROM test()`. PS: the [use of inheritance  in functions](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4678.987180995%40sss.pgh.pa.us) are only for parameters.